# How to get the dnn module version using c#

Tags: dnn9, dotnetnuke

I would like to get the version in a DotNetNuke Module.
I try:

```
new ModuleController().GetModule(this.ModuleId).ModuleVersion
```

but its always -1.

On the .dnn file I have this definition:

```
<package name="xxxx" type="Module" version="02.01.88">
```

How could I get the "02.01.88" string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that we could use:

```
new ModuleController().GetModule(this.ModuleId).DesktopModule.Version
```